# Porque lista não aceita [01,02,03,04]

Tags: python

Estou começando no Python, quero criar uma lista de numeros, queria usar

```
dezenas = [[01,02,03,04],[05,06,07,08],[09,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16],[17,18,19,20],
           [21,22,23,24],[25,26,27,28],[29,30,31,32],[33,34,35,36],[37,38,39,40],
           [41,42,43,44],[45,46,47,48],[49,50,51,52],[53,54,55,56],[57,58,59,60],
           [61,62,63,64],[65,66,67,68],[69,70,71,72],[73,74,75,76],[77,78,79,80],
           [81,82,83,84],[85,86,87,88],[89,90,91,92],[93,94,95,96],[97,98,99,00]]
```

Está dando erro quando começa com por `exemplo[01]`,alguém pode me ajuda!

Comment: Porquê `01` ? O numero é `1`

Answer (score 14):

"Dá erro porque está errado" :D

## Python 2

Em Python 2, sua sintaxe estaria errada, pois números prefixados por `0` seriam octais, e não existiria um octal `08` (os dígitos octais válidos são de 0 a 7).

Além disso, os resultados provavelmente não seriam o que você espera se usasse em situações como 027, por exemplo. Veja este print em Python 2:

```
>>> print 027 + 3
26
```

Isto porque 027 em octal equivale a 23 em decimal.

## Python 3

Em Python 3, para evitar esta confusão, decidiu-se não aceitar o prefixo zero, obrigando o programador a explicitar um octal desta forma: `0o27`, assim eliminando ambiguidades.

Desta forma, uma sequência de números começada por zero é um token inválido. Exceto decimais como `0.82` - que curiosamente aceitam ser escritos como `0000.82`.

Creio que nessas alturas do campeonato você já deve ter notado que a solução é não inventar moda, e representar os números como eles são:

```
dezenas = [[ 1, 2, 3, 4],[ 5, 6, 7, 8],[ 9,10,11,12] ...
```

Pode usar um espacinho para alinhar, se o problema for esse.

Comment: "Dá erro porque está errado" :D - Não consegui evitar uma pequena gargalhada haha :D

Comment: @Isac eu não consegui palavras melhores pra dizer, foi no sentido de "não se trata de nada obscuro, é erro elementar de sintaxe mesmo, conforme indicado no output" :D